# How to convert time string to indian standard time in React Js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

i am trying to get local time, from the only time string. i am getting the api response with only time string like 12:30 PM, I have Tried like below but its not working when the time is 00:00(i am getting 5:30 am) ,
but it is working for the other time, i have also tried using moment-timezone, but whenever my time is 00:00 i am geting 05:30 AM

```
{moment.utc(user.checkin_time, 'hh:mm A').local().format('hh:mm A')}
```

Comment: looks like you're using `moment` so see: [`moment timezone`](https://momentjs.com/timezone/). Alternatively you can use the js native [`Intl.DateTimeFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat) and pass a timezone option.

Comment: Yes i am using moment, from the API response i am not getting date, only TIME i am getting , what need to be done?

Comment: You'll need to install the [`moment-timezone`](https://momentjs.com/timezone/) plugin with data, then `moment.utc(user.checkin_time, 'hh:mm A').tz('Asia/Kolkata').format('hh:mm A')`

Comment: i am getting 05:30 AM if i have time  00:00 , i have also installed moment-timezone

Comment: [IST](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_Standard_Time) is +5:30, so that is correct.

Comment: i am getting utc time from api, i want it in indian time, so for 00:00 i need 12:00 Am instead of 5.30 am

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally with the help of @pilchard i found the answer

```
moment.utc(user.checkin_time, 'hh:mm A').tz('Asia/Kolkata').format('hh:mm A')
```